# Error undefined index php

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una pagina para un proyecto del colegio e intento mostrar unos comunicados. Este es el código donde solicito que comunicados quiero mostrar dependiendo de quien este logueado.

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['rol']=='administrador'){
     echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'alta_co.php\')">Nuevo Comunicado</button>';
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_L\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?b=administrador\'),cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?c=administrador\')">Ver Comunicados</button>';
    }
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['rol']=='Docente'){
 echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'alta_co.php\')">Nuevo Comunicado</button>';
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_L\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?b=Docente\'),cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?c=Docente\')">Ver Comunicados</button>';
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['rol']=='Padre'){
 echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'alta_co.php\')">Nuevo Comunicado</button>';
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_L\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?b=Padre\'),cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?c=Padre\')">Ver Comunicados</button>';
}
  ?>
```

Y el error Notice: Undefined index: b in mostrar_comunicados.php on line 5 me sale en estas lineas de codigo de mostrar_comunicados.php que es donde los mando arriba

```
$str_b = $_GET['b'];
$str_c =  $_GET['c'];
```

Les agradesco cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese error ocurre porque no estás pasando el parámetro "b" en la url.

Te recomiendo verificar si estás recibiendo esos parámetros y asignar un valor por defecto antes de usarlos:

```
$str_b = array_key_exists('b', $_GET) ? $_GET['b'] : '';
$str_c = array_key_exists('c', $_GET) ? $_GET['c'] : '';
```

En este ejemplo el valor por defecto es un string vacío, pero puedes asignarle el valor que quieras.

Comment: De hecho si le estoy pasando un valor a "b" en la url, en el primer cargar() en cada onclick le paso un valor a "b". O lo esoy pisando al llamar otro cargar()?

Comment: En cada botón llamas a la función "cargar" dos veces.
En la primera solo mandas el parámetro "b" y en la segunda solo mandas el parámetro "c".
Pero en el archivo "mostrar_comunicados.php" tratas de obtener ambos y es donde ocurre el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tus variables GET no están definidas, primero deberías de validarlo con un simple if y la función isset, que devolverán true siempre y cuando esas variables estén definidas, puedes intentar el siguiente código:

```
if( isset($_GET['b']) && isset($_GET['c']) ){
   $str_b = $_GET['b'];
   $str_c =  $_GET['c'];
}
```

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Gracias, ya edité con una pequeña explicación.